# iTunes Connect In-App Purchase multiple apps

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

We have two targets from the same code. Reason is to be able to localize the icon in the app store and on the device.  They have different App IDs, but we was hoping to use the same IAPs for both.

We use Urban Airship to look after the IAPs, but iTunes Connect doesn't allow us to enter the same Product ID in the different apps.

We don't really want to keep different sets of codes and IAPs, so is there any way of getting this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No.

In-app purchases require non-wildcarded App IDs (foo.bar.bang, not foo.bar.*).

App IDs must be different.

In-app purchases can only access their own App IDs available purchases.

I suggest you rethink the need for localized icons. (If there is text on your icon, you should definitely rethink it!)  Otherwise, genericize the icon.

Possible workaround (i think you can do this): both apps can use iCloud to access shared defaults. Unlock purchases made from one app in the other as identified by defaults.

Comment: aside: This need is more commonly wanted in "regular" and "HD" apps, which need to be separated into 2 apps.

Comment: or if you have separate iPhone/iPad apps with the same functionality (ie: non universal)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use the same subscription as @bshirley mentioned - according to https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/

But you can create two subscriptions and sync between the apps so your users will not pay twice for the same thing.

> Offering Subscriptions to Multiple Apps
>
> You can offer auto-renewable subscriptions to access multiple apps in your portfolio. Each app must be approved to use auto-renewable in-app purchases and must be published under the same developer name on the App Store.
>
> In iTunes Connect, **you’ll need to set up separate and equivalent auto-renewable in-app purchases in each app offered in the multi-app subscription so that users can subscribe from any app. To avoid users paying multiple times for the same offering, you are responsible for verifying that they are subscribers in one of the apps before showing any subscription options.** To do this, consider maintaining an account management system in which users create an account with your business to sign in to each app.